# How to get version of installed Windows if i'm in Recovery Console?

Tags: windows

I have an image of server HDD that have some version of Windows 2008 R2 installed. It's in reboot loop, so i need to use "repair install" on it to regain functionality.

Unfortunately, i don't know exact version of this server (for example "Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit Datacenter Edition English language") so i don't know what ISO file to use for repair install. Inserting random ISO files i have downloaded from MSD gives me only "image recovery/memory/command prompt" choice, no "repair install".

Is it possible to check exact version of installed Windows from recovery console so i can boot from same version ISO and use "repair install"?

Comment: Dunno if it works from the recovery console, but from the CLI, `wmic OS get OperatingSystemSKU` will return a number corresponding to the SKU number of your OS type and edition.

Comment: @HopelessN00b It works, but seems that it shows info about running operating system, the one on the dvd i booted recovery console from.